# javaSE.jar is causing an exception

Tags: codenameone

While working on a project i noticed that when using the rotate option in the simulator, an exception is raised:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: 
Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread
```

I created a new project that doesn't have that problem and after comparing them, i noticed that the javaSE.jar's size are different :

The javaSE.jar in the first project is 17883ko and the javaSE.jar in the second project is 17673ko

If I replace the jar in the first project, the exception goes away.

What is the cause of this ?

I am using Netbeans 8.2 with the latest CodeNameOne plugin.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1303)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1296)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1348)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$C.blit(JavaSEPort.java:820)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.sizeChanged(JavaSEPort.java:3399)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$35.actionPerformed(JavaSEPort.java:2550)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception you are getting

Comment: Thanks for the response. I edited my original message.

Answer (score 0):

You have an old jar. You need to update the client libs if you are running into issues. Right click the project, select: `Codename One` -> `Codename One Settings` -> `Basic` -> `Update Client Libs`.

When reporting issues always report against the up to date latest version after doing that.

Comment: I suppose you mean the "Update Project Libs" button.

It doesn't resolve the issue. I still get that exception in the simulator.

Comment: Is it the same stack with exact same line numbers after the update?

Comment: The stack trace is exactly the same. The javaSE.jar is still 17883ko.

Is this javaSE.jar file in the project directory updated when using the Update Project Libs option?

I tried to delete it before clicking the update button but it is not redownloaded.

Comment: Unfortunately this missed the code freeze for 3.7 so we now need to decide if this warrants a P1 bug. I see the issue it seems `sizeChanged` calls `canvas.blit();` from the native swing EDT which is prohibited.

Comment: We reviewed the fix for 3.7 and we'll push an update that includes this fix https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2136